React.js issue while running 'npm start'
I wanted to run an existing project of React in my desktop and having this issue when I put npm start command. I am using JetBrains WebStorm IDE.
I tried the command npm start in the terminal to run the project. But it shows some error:

D:\All Project\only_landing_page\only_landing_page> npm start

npm error Missing script: "start"
npm error
npm error Did you mean one of these?
npm error   npm star # Mark your favorite packages
npm error   npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
npm error
npm error To see a list of scripts, run:
npm error   npm run
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: 
C:\Users\folder\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-08-25T04_12_38_553Z-debug-0.log

PS D:\All Project\only_landing_page\only_landing_page>


Are you in the folder where the package.json is? If so, the error is as it says, you don't have a start script in your package.json (https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/using-npm/scripts). Google the error message, there's heaps of SO posts about all the causes of this error
